# Get URL not rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a re-write rule in .htaccess file that created SEO-friendly URL

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /pages/story.$1.php [L]
```

so mydomain.com/pages/story.books.php will appear as mydomain.com/books

Is there any way to pass additional parameters within URL?

> mydomain.com/books?history

But, additional parameter is optional and may not be there altogether.

I've tried the following but it broke my rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /pages/story.$1.php?info=$2 [L]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can send variables with ?x=112&y=dddd

Comment: Just add `QSA` flag to make it `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /pages/story.$1.php [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([A-za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?username=$1 [NC,L] # domain.com/post/name 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ profil.php?id=$1&menu=$2 [NC,L] # domain.com/cat/post/id 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ profil.php?id=$1&menu=$2&page=$3 [NC,L]
```